# Problem with Simulation Results VS Tested Results for a signal

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, pwm, ltspice, lm386

For the circuit shown i am having some trouble wondering why my tested signal looks like this (i understand that it could be clipping) but when i measure my circuit in the simulation it is correct? What could be causing these issues. I have to make a signal play through a speaker and just dont get what the issue could be? The amps are 2 x lm6484 and 1 x lm386. The circuit works perfectly and plays the sound as it should (with the 50k resistor being the potentiometer) but i just dont get what coiuld cause this change to the signal?

[image]

Could it potentially be a faulty breadboard. Also on another note i have a problem that when a different recording is played, the gain of the amp isnt 20, why is this?

[image]

Comment: The snapshot shows a (somewhat) square wave over 60kHz, if I interpret it correctly. What did you expect from an audio part operating at such high frequencies?

Comment: Also, the simluation shows the voltage at n007, but from the schematic it is not clear which node it is. Maybe it is C1/C4/U1_5?

Comment: Are you actually using a 5V supply, lm386 is good for maybe 3vpp into 8 on a 5 v supply

Comment: Yes using 5v power supply, and I get it's a square wave proved just after the amps output, I just don't get why I dont get the graph like the simulation